# Should duplicate favicons use rel canonical or redirects?

Tags: images, canonical-url

I have a website running across multiple subdomains and each one has a favicon.ico icon file in the root of each subdomain. Each icon for each subdomain is exactly the same. Is there an easy way I can declare every icon but one with rel canonical? Or is it worth redirecting users to the original icon even though each icon is about 900 bytes?

Comment: Why are you worried about duplication?   These icons are unlikely to appear in any search results, not even image search.   I can't imagine they would cause any SEO problems no matter how you deal with them.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't be concerned about duplicate favicons - it is common across many sites to have duplicates.I would not action canonicals or redirects as it is not likely to have any SEO impact.